# Batch File skip or ignore "Script has stopped working" error

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling

I have a batch script where I call a program several times, that is failing. This is a known issue and not by me. The crash is not intended, but for my case, it does not matter, as my desired output was generated before this crash. Every time it fails, the following known window appears: 
[image: program failure].

As said, I don't care about that misbehavior of the application and I am happy with the result processed before the failure. But in my script, I call that program several times and I always have to cancel that operation. I only want the script to terminate without showing that window, similar to Linux systems where the execution aborts and the command line can be used without any interaction. An example with an Segmentation Fault can be seen in the image found online:

[image: Source: user liuqun https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/issues/607]

How can I call the program that this window does not pop up and the script works with no action by the user?

Comment: This, cannot be done I think; you cannot prevent the window. But I think you can `taskkill` it with a continuous loop.

Comment: In *Control Panel* -> *Action Center* -> *Problem Reporting Settings* -> *Never check for solutions...* can be checked, so that window does not appear. Possibly, the setting is stored in the registry.

Comment: @michael_heath close to the solution. But still, a window indicating the crash appears.

Comment: To avoid the window showing, `reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "DontShowUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 1`. To show again, use data `/d 0`. Reference: [WER Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/wer-settings). Can also use `HKCU` hive for just the user. You will still get Crash Dumps etc.